# AWS DMS connect to on premise SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, migration, connectivity, aws

I am working through the process of migrating a SQL Server 2014 DB to AWS Redshift. I have converted the schema and provisioned a PostgreSQL Redshift instance. Now in AWS-DMS->Create Migration->Database endpoints->Connect source and target database endpoints I am not clear on the following:

```
Server name: ???
```

What do I need to specify for AWS to see this? My SQL Servername is 'SERVERNAME'. But I presume AWS would need an IP address of my machine as well? Also - I have not opened the Server up for internet access - it is a local install behind a firewall. How should I go about allowing AWS to access it?

Then for the target database connection details:

```
Server name: ???
```

Is this the full endpoint or just the server name without the ...amazon.com extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network address of a server instance (its server network address or Endpoint URL) contains the port number of its endpoint, as well as the system and domain name of its host computer. The port number uniquely identifies a specific server instances.

You can try for example below format as we use for Database Mirroring :

`TCP://srv5.corp.abc.com:5022`

For your reference:

- [Configure SQL Server Database Mirroring Using SSMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2464/configure-sql-server-database-mirroring-using-ssms/)
- [The Database Mirroring Endpoint (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179511.aspx)